# UJS partial rendering in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to get my head around how to implement UJS in Rails (specifically, Rails 3 with jQuery). I've worked through [Ryan's Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript), and can follow what to do when submitting a form via AJAX, but I'm having trouble extending this concept to attaching a javascript function to a html element in my view files. Ultimately, I would like to be able to create a form where a different partial is rendered depending upon which radio button from a series is selected. Should I be looking at using the Prototype legacy helpers for this? And when do I need to create a .js.erb file?

Sorry for the newbie question, I've been unable to find much that explicitly outlines the concept of UJS and how to use it in a Rails app/switch over code from a RJS approach. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the `remote => true` on the form, your data will go to the server and all javascript returned will simply be executed in the context of the page, so here is a simple example:

```
<%= form_tag '/action_path', :remote => true do %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'partial', 'one' %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'partial', 'two' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'select' %>
<% end %>

<div id="partial_holder">

</div>
```

On the server

```
def action
  #do whatever you want with parameters
end
```

On the action.js.erb file

```
$('#partial_holder').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => params[:partial])) %>")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - trouble is, I don't want the form submission itself to be AJAXy, just the elements within the form...

Comment: If only parts of the form will be AJAX sent, you'll have to either make more than one form or simply make custom javascript to send requests with your elements inside the form. It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you want to do without any kind of code or example :/

Comment: From what I've read it seems like Rails 3 requires developers to write more of their own javascript by removing a lot of helper methods, so thanks for the comment about the custom javascript - I'm just going to have to brush up on my js skills a bit!

Comment: I was having the same problem as @Sonia, adding <div id="partial_holder"> saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

On the action.js.erb file

```
$('#partial_holder').html(<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => params[:partial])) %>)
```

The above line has a minor mistake, the ruby tags inside html method should be inside quotes. The following will work.

```
$('#partial_holder').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => params[:partial])) %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following links for more insight into the concept of UJS:

http://www.railsinside.com/tips/451-howto-unobtrusive-javascript-with-rails-3.html

http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3

http://therailworld.com/posts/26-Using-Prototype-and-JQuery-with-Rails3-UJS-

http://www.metaskills.net/2010/1/29/unobtrusive-js-in-rails-3-with-prototype

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reasons for me the abovementioned solution did not work. This did:

```
Element.replace('element_id', '<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>"foo")) %>');
```

Note the ' that surrounds the ruby block.